# Power BI loses sorting between two different chart

Tags: sorting, powerbi

I don't know if this is a recurring problem or not, but I have a Power BI solution which has a pie chart and a bar graph. The bar graph is sorted in descending order by a "Value" field. Initially my Power BI file is loading with the below viz. I want to filter the right graph to bring TOP 5 countries name by descending order of their value when a user clicks on pie-chart on left side. The left side is the category of each countries viz. 0,1,2 & 3.

[image]

Below happens when I click Category "0". As you can see Power BI gives 9 results (highlighted by dark green)

[image]

Same happens for Category "1". Again I see more than 5 values.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check interactions under format tab. Select the primary visual (in your case pie visual) than click on the filter tab on seconday visual (Bar chart). Default filter is highlight.

[image: Format Tab]
[image: Switch interaction type filter from highlight]